# Toggle a python boolean from iOS

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I am following this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server tutorial.

I got this stuff working nice, and being a total noob at this, i can not for the life of me figure out how to add a Python boolean to the 'chatserver.py' document mentioned in the tutorial, pasted below.

Not only do I want to add one, but also to toggle it from the iPhone app with a button, and then request to know it back from the server.

Like, 
 a button to toggle boolean (How to send a toggle message) and how to ask the server what the state of the boolean is

Apologies for this very open question.

Here is the current server: (Uber-complicated, wohoo!)

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class IphoneChat(Protocol):
def connectionMade(self):
    #self.transport.write("""connected""")
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    self.factory.clients.remove(self)

def dataReceived(self, data):
    #print "data is ", data
    a = data.split(':')
    if len(a) > 1:
        command = a[0]
        content = a[1]

        msg = ""
        if command == "iam":
            self.name = content
            msg = self.name + " has joined"

        elif command == "msg":
            msg = self.name + ": " + content

        print msg

        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(msg)

def message(self, message):
    self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Are you looking for a separate boolean value for each connection, or one for each client (defined in some larger way—e.g., the `name` from an `iam` command), or one shared by all users?

Comment: Also, what part of this question is at all iOS-specific or ObjC-related, other than the fact that your chat protocol is named `IphoneChat`?

Comment: @abarnert I would say it is, as the tutorial i am working with is for iPhone

Comment: If you really think it's Objective-C-related, why didn't you post any Objective-C code? The tutorial you linked to even shows how to test this server with `telnet` before you've even written any iOS code. If you can do that, it's not iOS-specific.

Comment: @abarnert Its not ios -spesific- but as the linked tutorial is for iphone, and the data handeled by the script is made for this purpose, I felt like that was an appropiate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to decide whether you're talking about a separate boolean value for each connection, or a shared value for everyone, or something in between (e.g., each *user* has a separate one, available once they log in with `iam`).

I'll make it per-connection, which I'll do by storing it in as a `Protocol` instance attribute. You could make it globally shared by storing it in as a module global, or a `Protocol` class attribute, etc. If you want something more fancy, you'll want a global/class/etc. mapping of some kind.

```
def connectionMade(self):
    #self.transport.write("""connected""")
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print "clients are ", self.factory.clients
    self.boolean_flag = False

def dataReceived(self, data):
    ...
    if command == "iam":
        self.name = content
        msg = self.name + " has joined"
    elif command = "set":
        self.boolean_flag = True
        msg = self.name + " has set his flag"
    elif command = "clear":
        self.boolean_flag = False
        msg = self.name + " has cleared his flag"
    elif command = "get":
        self.message("Your flag is {}\n".format(self.boolean_flag))
        msg = self.name + " has checked his flag"
    ...
```

That's all there is to it.

---

However, it's worth noting that your code is not going to work at all in the first place.

You've created a generic `internet.protocol`. This means your `dataReceived` gets called any time some bytes come in. Those bytes could be half a message, or a message and a half. So, I might send you `"iam:abarnert"` and then `"msg:hello"`, but you're going to see that as, say, `"ia"`, then `"m:abarnertmsg:h"`, and then `"ello"`.

The worst thing is that when you're testing this all on a single computer, or on certain types of LAN, it actually *seems* to work—each send on one side is received as exactly one receive on the other side. But as soon as you put it on the internet, it will fail completely.

This is why Twisted comes with a bunch of slightly-higher-level protocols to do, e.g., newline-separated, or netstrings, or whatever else you want. But if you just use the lowest-level raw internet protocol, you have to handle buffering and delimiting and all those things on your own. Which you don't want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I realise that I should have specified the type. Just a random boolean, working of the tutorial, toggled. So it might just be something named pancake that is true or false, aslong as it can be toggeled by chat. Will above code still do the work for that?

Comment: And about that twisted stuff, i'm just learning and playing with this stuff, so it wont step outside of LAN. Whatever you are talking about seems pretty complicated, so putting that off until I understand the basics.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't matter what the boolean is called. If you want to call it `pancake` instead of `boolean_flag`, just change the name in all places, and it still works the same. If you want to add a `toggle` command, just made it do `self.boolean_flag = not self.boolean_flag`. If you want it to start with a random value, use `self.boolean_flag = random.choice((False, True))` instead of `False`. And so on. It's just a normal variable.

Comment: About the twisted stuff… it's not complicated, and it's fundamental to doing any networking programming. You definitely need to learn what a protocol is before you start defining protocols. Also, following a tutorial by a guy who doesn't understand that (he seems to think that `NSInputStream` and `internet.protocol.Protocol` both give you a line at a time, which is just plain wrong) seems like a very bad idea. (Also, he doesn't seem to realize that real iOS devices change IP addresses, and drop and reconnect connections, frequently.)

Comment: I see.. That makes alot of sense. Guess its true what they say about the internet not being a reliable source of information. Do you have any resource thats better for learning this stuff to noobs like me?

Comment: I don't know of a tutorial that shows both sides. But if you google for twisted tutorials, you can build a (command-line) client and server first, and then google for iOS socket networking tutorials and build an iOS client later.